# using ffmpeg to resize video with black bars

Tags: ffmpeg

i have a video with resolution 720:576 and i want it to have the ratio 16:9, e.g. 1024:576 with black bars on the sides. don't know if it matters, but i am working with ffmpeg for windows. After research i tried the solution i found on 2 related questions:

```
-i .\video.mp4 -vf scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1024:576:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1 out.mp4
```

but i get an output that "ow-iw" was not recognized. Here is the complete output. unfortunatly it is in german(as am i) if u tell me how to change the output language i will provide it in english:

```
ow-iw : Die Benennung "ow-iw" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des
Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:119
+ ... :576:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1024:576:(ow-iw)/2:(oh- ...
+                                                             ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ow-iw:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Enclose the pad exprs in single quotes.

Comment: u mena like `-i .\out.mp4 -vf scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1024:576:('ow-iw')/2:('oh-ih')/2,setsar=1 out2.mp4`? this gives me `[NULL @ 00000152ec6700c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ow-iw'
ow-iw: Invalid argument`

Comment: No. the whole expression: `'(ow-iw)/2'`